# Applying loops for get_historical function (from Bomrang)

Tags: r, loops

I'm using get_historical_weather function from Bomrang package. 
Instead of specifying manually lat and lon details (e.g. get_historical(latlon=c(-28.016666,153.399994),type="rain")) I need to use lat and lon details from existing list. 
I've tried using for loop, without any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there is data for the provided lat/lon combinations?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel  , I'm quite new to using R, therefore I'm sure that my loop code is incorrect.                                                                                                                  
I've used following code. lat contains list of latitudes, and lon contains list of longitude details:         

'for (i in 1:length(lat), j in 1:length(lon)){
  get_historical(latlon = c(lat, lon),type="rain" '
  
  
}

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is using the `purrr` package

```r
library(bomrang)
library(purrr)
coords <- structure(list(lat = c(-28.01666, -33.8688), 
                         lon = c(153.399994, 151.2093)), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

x <- purrr::map2(.x = coords$lat, .y = coords$lon, .f = ~get_historical(latlon = c(.x, .y), type = "rain"))
#> Closest station: 040764 (GOLD COAST SEAWAY)
#> Data saved as /tmp/RtmpJkn04r/IDCJAC0009_040764_1800_Data.csv
#> Closest station: 066062 (SYDNEY (OBSERVATORY HILL))
#> Data saved as /tmp/RtmpJkn04r/IDCJAC0009_066062_1800_Data.csv
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>